# Как создать docker образ из существующей postgres бд?

Tags: postgresql, docker

То-есть чтобы в контейнере был образ моей локальной бд, со всеми данными.
Или может быть есть способ импорта данных из локальной бд, в бд находящуюся в контейнере.

upd. [image: pg_res]

Что еще необходимо добавить к этой команде?

Comment: Делаете дамп локальной БД командой pg_dump и восстанавливаете ее в БД, запущенную в docker командой pg_restore.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA а есть пример использования? К сожалению пока не совсем понимаю этот синтаксис

Comment: бд в контейнере может напрямую работать с локальной бд, достаточно только примонтировать в контейнер папку с данными

Comment: @user7860670 здорово, а как это сделать?)

Comment: Использовать при создании контейнера аргумент --mount